# NSArray getter method not returning right value

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm making a program where one Class (classA) generates a random number and adds it to a mutable array.  A view controller (viewControllerA) calls a method from classA and receives the array of random numbers and stores it in its own array.

I have another class (classB) that needs the same array. After viewcontrollerA is finished doing what it needs to do with the array, it calls the setter method for an array in classB. I call NSLog in the setter and getter methods for the array in classB to check to see if it loads.

```
-(void)setRandomNumberArray:(NSArray *)randomNumberArray{
_randomNumberArray = randomNumberArray;

NSLog(@"%@ setter", _randomNumberArray);
}
```

-

```
-(NSArray *)randomNumberArray{
if (!_randomNumberArray) {
    _randomNumberArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
}

NSLog(@"%@ getter", _randomNumberArray);
return _randomNumberArray;
}
```

When I call the setter method in viewControlerA, NSLog returns the value of the array.
When I call the getter method in viewControllerB, NSLog prints nothing from the getter method.

```
2012-05-29 23:57:43.589 SwipeGame[8603:f803] (
) getter
```

It's obviously setting the array but not retaining it for when i want to get it. What is going on? I've tried multiple other techniques and it always sets the array but doesn't retain it for when i want to "get" the array.

the property for my array is set to retain btw..

UPDATE:
Yes I am using ARC. my property declaration is:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *randomNumberArray
```

SOLVED:
Thanks for all your help! It was a problem with instances.

Comment: There might be some problem in the memory management. One more thing use property and synthesize keywords for generating the setter and getter methods.

Comment: I usually do. for this purpose i manually implemented the getter and the setter methods to run NSLog to make sure it was getting set correctly

Comment: Can you include your property and ivar declarations and if you are using ARC or not?

Comment: Probably you are using the getter on a different instance. Add some `NSLog(@"ClassA %p", classAInstance);` before you use the getter and setter methods to make sure the two instances of ClassA are equal. The NSLog prints the memory adress of your objects. They must match.

Comment: Yes that was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your setter method does not mention viewControllerB. You are just setting an internal variable. How is viewControllerB going to know about the array having been set?

The easiest way is to just use `@properties` and `@synthesize`:

```
// in A
viewControllerB.array = _array;
```

As for the retain question: if you use ARC you should not worry about it.

Comment: should it mention viewControllerB? I was taught that a model should not "talk" to the view control in an MVC. Either way...if it's set, shouldn't i be able to get it?

Comment: It seems it is not set. You should call the setter method on the viewControllerB, from A. The setter definition should be in B. Much easier going with simple @properties.

Comment: i've tried that and same exact result. from viewControllerB I tried to set an NSArray property and set it to the array from viewControllerB and NSLog will print for set but prints empty for get. also tried getting the array directly from classA and same situation.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the types. Be careful not to mix up `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. To create an `NSMutableArray` you have to do this: `mutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:normalArray];`. Also, you should delete your getter and setter methods and log like this: `NSLog(@"%@", self.randomNumberArray);`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use ARC?

ARC version bellow:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *_randomNumberArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *randomNumberArray;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize randomNumberArray = _randomNumberArray;
- (void)setRandomNumberArray:(NSMutableArray *)randomNumberArray {
    _randomNumberArray = randomNumberArray;
    NSLog(@"%@ setter", _randomNumberArray);
}

- (NSMutableArray *) randomNumberArray {
  if ( _randomNumberArray == nil )
    _randomNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"%@ getter", _randomNumberArray);
  return _randomNumberArray;
}
@end
```

Not ARC version bellow:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
  NSMutableArray *_randomNumberArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *randomNumberArray;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize randomNumberArray = _randomNumberArray;
- (void)setRandomNumberArray:(NSMutableArray *)randomNumberArray {
    [_randomNumber release];
    _randomNumberArray = randomNumberArray;
    [_randomNumberArray retain];
    NSLog(@"%@ setter", _randomNumberArray);
}

- (NSMutableArray *) randomNumberArray {
  if ( _randomNumberArray == nil )
    _randomNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"%@ getter", _randomNumberArray);
  return _randomNumberArray;
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [_randomNumberArray release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating this random number array using an `NSMutableArray`, and passing that to the setter, the array could be mutated later by the caller (e.g. all items removed) and the array can change from under your feet.

For types like `NSArray` and `NSString` which have mutable subtypes, you should declare your property as `copy` instead of `strong`. This will ensure the array passed to you cannot be mutated at a later date by somebody else. Copy performance is not a problem because the regular immutable types handle copies very efficiently.